# How to create movement like Snake vs Block in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to re-create the popular SnakeVSBlock mobile game. Most of the physics are pretty straight forward but I cannot seem to re-create the snake movement. What's special about the snake movement in the game is that the previous node follows the next ones path perfectly, both in X and in Y. This is my current code which does work as a snake movement but does not follow the exact path of the next node. I'm wondering if anyone has a solution to this.

```
public void Move()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && GameManager.Instance.IsGameOver() == false && Nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        Vector3 curPos = Input.mousePosition;
        curPos.z = -1;
        curPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curPos);
        Nodes[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(curPos.x - Nodes[0].position.x, 0) * 20;

    if (Nodes[0].position.x > 2.56f)
    {
        Nodes[0].position = new Vector2(2.56f,Nodes[0].position.y);
    }
    else if (Nodes[0].position.x < -2.56f)
    {
        Nodes[0].position = new Vector2(-2.56f, Nodes[0].position.y);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < Nodes.Count; i++)
    { 
        Vector2 newPos = new Vector2(Nodes[i-1].position.x, Nodes[i].position.y);
        if (GameManager.Instance.GetPoweredUp())
        {
            Nodes[i].position = Vector2.Lerp(Nodes[i].position, newPos, Time.deltaTime * 14);
        }
        else
        {
            Nodes[i].position = Vector2.Lerp(Nodes[i].position, newPos, Time.deltaTime * 10);
        }

    }
}
```

UPDATE: I changed the basic logic for the snake movement in my game. Instead of having the snake move upwards, the snake stays in the same position and the blocks move downwards. However I still can't obtain the smooth snake movement like in the real games. Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do, you should approach this in the reverse order.
So, if you have the nodes 0 to n:

- Start from the n-th node
- Assing this node the position of the (n-1)-th node
- Then for each i node, assign it the position of the i-1 node
- When you moved all the nodes, move the node 0 according to the user input.

It should look like this:

```
public void Move()
{
    int n = Nodes.Count;

    if (n > 0)
    {
        for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            _curNode = Nodes[i];
            _nextNode = Nodes[i - 1];

            Vector3 pos = _nextNode.transform.position;
            pos.z = Nodes[0].position.z;

            _curNode.tranform.position = pos;
        }

        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Nodes[0].Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * horizontalInput * 10);
        Nodes[0].Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 4);

        if (Nodes[0].position.x > 2.90)
        {
            Nodes[0].position = new Vector2(2.90f, Nodes[0].position.y);
        }
        else if (Nodes[0].position.x < -2.90)
        {
            Nodes[0].position = new Vector2(-2.90f, Nodes[0].position.y);
        }
    }    
}
```

Also, unless you somehow increment the two LerpTime variables, you're misusing the Lerp function, and you don't need it in this context either. 
This is an awesomely clear guide on what Lerp really means and how to use it properly:
http://lunarlabs.pt/blog/post/the-art-of-lerp

Comment: This is pretty close to what I need but not exactly there, the different nodes are too close together and when I try to increase the space between them, the nodes dont follow eachother perfectly anymore. Would you have any idea how to do increase the spacing? Also thank you for the lerp information, that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The old mobile game "snake" where you collect little squares has the same sort of movement. The solution then was that the parts of the snake don't actually move, just each frame you add a bit to the head and take one off the tail.

The reason why that approach works with snake but not immediately in this snake vs blocks game is that the former is discrete, and the latter is continuous.

One way to solve this is that each body part could always be lerping towards the one above it and when it gets there, it teleports back. This would give the illusion of the snake moving forward, when actually the body parts are stuck in place, just like the old snake game.

This works on paper but I have no idea how it will perform. However, if you are really desperate you could consider giving this a try.